# Multi threaded curl handling multiple connections at the same time

Tags: c++, c, libcurl

Is curl_multi interface spawning new threads internally to handle multiple requests concurrently? Is it equal to spawning threads manually and just using curl_easy handles? What is more performant. I need to make up to 1000 concurrent requests.

https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/multithread.html

Is using curl_multi equal to the example in the link above?

From: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html

> Enable multiple simultaneous transfers in the same thread without making it complicated for the application.

What does it mean? How does it handle multiple transfers in the same thread? I could as well create 100 threads with 100 curl_easy handles and make requests there.

Maybe the question should be: When to use multiple threads and when to use curl_multi.

Comment: "*Is curl_multi interface spawning new threads internally to handle multiple requests concurrently?*" No. As the documentation (quoted by yourself) says: "*Enable multiple simultaneous transfers **in the same thread***".

Comment: As for how: The documentation links to https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_perform.html, which shows an example using `select`. There's also https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_socket_action.html, which looks like an interface to epoll/kqueue/whatever.

Comment: C or C++? They're different languages. Choose one.

Comment: @tambre They're not that different, the question is about libcurl in general so that doesn't matter, it applies to both.

Comment: @i'm your huckleberry Then you're mistaken. Most of the things you'd write in C one way, you'd write in C++ completely differently. C++ has templates, smart pointers, more library features, various other syntactic changes, arguments are passed differently, mangling is different, C++-style casts, lambdas, etc etc.

Comment: @tambre libcurl is C API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no easy or simple answer. libcurl allows you and your application to make the decision and supports working in either mode.

The libcurl multi interface is a single-core single-thread way to do a large amount of parallel transfers in the same thread. It allows for easy reuse of caches, connections and more. That has its clear advantages but will make it CPU-bound in that single CPU.

Doing multi-threaded transfers will make each thread/handle has its own cache and connection pool etc which will change when they will be useful, but will make the transfers less likely to be CPU-bound when you can spread them out over a larger set of cores/CPUs.

Which the right design decision is for you, is not easy for us to tell.

Comment: From `everything.curl.dev`: "multi_socket supports multiple parallel transfers—all done in the same single thread—and have been used to run several tens of thousands of transfers in a single application." So I guess, for pretty much any application running on a modern desktop/laptop CPU `multi_socket` will be good enough?

Answer (score 3):

No all the connections on a single curl_multi handle operate on the same thread. It uses a single select/poll/epoll event loop and non-blocking sockets to process all the connection concurrently on the same thread.