# LibCurl parallel http request in a multi threaded environment

Tags: c++, multithreading, libcurl

Currently, I am creating a pool for curl easy handle to make parallel HTTP requests. But this is blocking.

Here is my implementation:

```
class CurlHttpClient
{
public:
    ...

private:
    CURL* m_curl = nullptr;
    std::mutex m_mtx;
    std::stack<CURL*> m_poolCurlHandle;
    CURL* getCurlHandleFromPool();
    void pushCurlHandle(CURL* curlHandle);
};

CURL* CurlHttpClient::getCurlHandleFromPool()
{
    CURL* pCurlHandle = nullptr;
    std::scoped_lock lock(m_mtx);
    {
        if (!m_poolCurlHandle.empty())
        {
            pCurlHandle = m_poolCurlHandle.top();
            m_poolCurlHandle.pop();
        }
        return pCurlHandle;
    }
    return curl_easy_duphandle(m_curl);
}


void CurlHttpClient::pushCurlHandle(CURL* curlHandle)
{
    std::scoped_lock lock(m_mtx);
    m_poolCurlHandle.push(curlHandle);
}

int CurlHttpClient::request(const std::string& requestUrl, std::string& responseBuffer)
{
    
    CURL* curlHandle = getCurlHandleFromPool();
    
    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void*)&responseBuffer);
    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, requestUrl.c_str());

    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curlHandle);
    
    int httpResponseCode = 0;
    curl_easy_getinfo(curlHandle, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &httpResponseCode);
    pushCurlHandle(curlHandle);
    return httpResponseCode;
}


// Example Client
int main()
{
CurlHttpClient client;
...
std::thread t1([&] { std::string response; std::string url;  client.request(url, response); //do something with response});
std::thread t2([&] { std::string response; std::string url;  client.request(url, response); //do something with response});
std::thread t3([&] { std::string response; std::string url;  client.request(url, response); //do something with response});
std::thread t4([&] { std::string response; std::string url;  client.request(url, response); //do something with response});

t1.join();
t2.join();
t3.join();
t4.join();
}
```

Here you could see that I am returning responses individually for each request as soon as it is received.

I read that curl multi-interface is better in handling the parallel request. I have seen some examples of multi-interface setup and all the examples are accumulating the request and firing the multi perform. But I am not sure how to return the data immediately to the client when an individual response is received and keep waiting for another response to arrive.

Is multi-interface helpful in my particular scenario? If so how can I return an individual response immediately when it is received?

Comment: Multi-interface works in a single thread, not multiple thread. The design pattern is very different.

Comment: Maybe you can check this question, it might have the answer for you too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44739178/multi-threaded-curl-handling-multiple-connections-at-the-same-time

Comment: Yes, I have seen those multi-interface examples, but it doesn't answer my question on how to get individual responses immendiately

Answer (score 0):

For your question on how to monitor the progress of a given handle, the best way is to use a callback function attached to the corresponding handle to check and react to the progress of the job :

https://everything.curl.dev/libcurl/callbacks/progress

You attach the callback by calling curl_easy_setopt with the option CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION.

There is no callback for the end of the job, but CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION will be called very shortly after a job is done, so except if you have very thigh real time constraints, it will do the job.

Comment: when using the multi interface, the curl_multi_info_read() function will return info about when each individual handle/transfer is complete

Comment: I think the multi-interface is not ideal in this particular scenario.